# How do I create a TLS connection to a Cloudflare-protected website?

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

I've been trying to connect to a website using `tls` library to view information about the certificate:

```js
const socket = require('tls').connect({ host: 'agma.io', port: 443 }, () => {
  const cert = socket.getPeerCertificate(true)
  console.log(cert)
})
```

And noticed that it doesn't work for websites that have Cloudflare protection on them.
How do I connect to them then?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const socket = require('tls').connect({ host: 'agma.io', servername: 'agma.io', port: 443 }, () => {
  const cert = socket.getPeerCertificate(true)
  console.log(cert)
})
```

Servername property.